# Hardware (usb ethernet, wifi) cannot be used when a fresh installation and update using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, usb, kernel, 22.04

the default kernel is 5.19.0-32-generic, and a fresh installation of ubuntu 22.04 LTS made it successful to be used, both the usb ethernet and the usb wifi (netgear A6210).

Until I installed the nvidia-driver, the kernel was updated to 5.19.0-50-generic, and even "apt-mark" the hold the kernel version didn't help.

So, the phenomenon is the original hardware cannot work on a newly updated kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the auto-loaded modules, I found that only 33 modules loaded by 5.19.0-50-generic, which was 114 when using 5.19.0-32-generic.
the solution is very simple:

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-50-generic
```

A stable reproducible bug, easy to fix, bang bang bang.

Comment: make sure to install `linux-module-extra-...` not `linux-module-...` as the former was already installed for me and sent me on a wild goose chase